# iOS: make different backgroundColor for tableView and tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, view, tableview

Here is what i am trying to archive

- my main view has red color with gradient.
- tableHeaderView should has a clear color (because it's a view with rounded corners, so it should be clear in some parts to display rounded corners).
- tableView(except header) should has a white color. Even if it has only one cell, the bottom space below that cell should be white.

My view hierarchy is simple: I have a tableView on top of main view

```
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        ...
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        ...
        tableView.tableHeaderView = someView (with clear color)
```

So, after that settings, I have tableview with clear background color, if I have one cell(I set its background color to white), space below that cell is clear. But it should be white. How can I get that?

--- solved:

```
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        if let tableFooterView = tableView.tableFooterView {
            let bigFooterView = UIView()
            bigFooterView.backgroundColor = .white
            tableFooterView.addSubview(bigFooterView)

            bigFooterView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            tableFooterView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bigFooterView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tableFooterView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            tableFooterView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bigFooterView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tableFooterView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            tableFooterView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bigFooterView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tableFooterView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            tableFooterView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bigFooterView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*2))
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the table footer to a white view.

> let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: someHeight) footerView.backgroundColor = .white
>
> tableView.tableFooterView = footerView

Comment: Sorry, forgot to set height.